# Why does it rotate 90 degrees when I add text to the picture?

Tags: php, watermark

I want to add a text in the middle of a photo taken with a phone camera. When I add the text, I get the picture turned 90 degrees. What could be the reason for this?

```
<?php

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('B.jpg');

$font = '/var/www/html/watermarkke/Signika/static/Signika-Bold.ttf';

$fontsize = 128;

// img rgb renkleri ile text rengini bel R,G,B,alpha
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($img,255,0,0,75);

$text="Why is the picture rotating?";

$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

$text_size = imagettfbbox($fontsize,0,$font,$text);

$text_width = max($text_size[2], $text_size[4]) - min($text_size[0], $text_size[6]);
$text_height = max($text_size[5], $text_size[7]) - min($text_size[1], $text_size[3]);

// Center

$centerX = CEIL(($width - $text_width) / 2);
$centerY = CEIL(($height - $text_height) / 2);

if($centerX < 0) {$centerX = 0; }
if($centerY < 0) {$centerY = 0; }


// IMG SIZE ROTATE X Y COLOR FONT TEXT
imagettftext($img,$fontsize,0,$centerX,$centerY,$color,$font,$text);
imagepng($img,'destination/B.jpg');
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Original picture as below
[image]

When I add the article with php, it is as follows.
[image]

Comment: It's possible that the photo is actually sideways already, but when you are viewing it it is being reoriented. Photos can contain metadata about whether they are sideways or not, and a lot of photo display things can detect it and adjust the photo for you (without physically changing the original).

Comment: https://medium.com/thetiltblog/fixing-rotated-mobile-image-uploads-in-php-803bb96a852c